# Makeglossaries and Perl warning: Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex

Tags: texstudio

I'm trying to run Makeglossaries. However, I get this warning message in the log file:

```
Processo iniciado: makeglossaries.exe "document-glossario"

Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@input{ <-- HERE (.+)\.aux}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 634.

Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@newglossary\s*\{(.*)\}{ <-- HERE (.*)}{(.*)}{(.*)}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 643. Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@newglossary\s*\{(.*)\}{(.*)}{ <-- HERE (.*)}{(.*)}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 643. Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@newglossary\s*\{(.*)\}{(.*)}{(.*)}{ <-- HERE (.*)}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 643.

Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@xdylanguage\s*{([^}]+)}{ <-- HERE ([^}]*)}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 674. Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\\@gls\@codepage\s*{([^}]+)}{ <-- HERE ([^}]*)}/ at C:\Users\user_001\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 680.

Processo concluído normalmente
```

I have make a google search, it seems a script glossary "bug" using this new perl 5.22 version. However, I have no idea how to fix it. If anyone could help, please.

---

ActivePearl Version 5.22.1.2201

[image: ActivePearl Version 5.22.1.2201]

---

TeXstudio Version is 2.10.8

---

Output PDF file seens ok.

Original LaTeX test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Results ok

[image: Output file ok]

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue? I'm running ActivePerl 5.24.1.2402 and TXS 2.12.6. No issues here.